# add labels bar chart

Tags: visualization, matplotlib

There is this dataframe:

```
print(df)
```

[image]

```
df.plot.bar(figsize=(10,5),fontsize=14,)
plt.title('counts',fontsize=15)

plt.show()
```

[image]
barh:

```
df.plot(kind='barh')
```

How can I add value labels on this bar and barh chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, adding text to the plot must be done manually. See the example below.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
df.plot.bar(ax=ax, fontsize=14)
for i, v in enumerate(df['counts']):
    ax.text(i + .25, v + 3, str(v))
```

Similarly, you can do for the horizontal barplot.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
df.plot.barh(ax=ax, fontsize=14)
for i, v in enumerate(df['counts']):
    ax.text(v + 3, i + .25,  str(v))
```

Comment: thank you very much